# run executable linux file without extension in elementary os

Tags: pantheon-files, applications, files

so as the title says i have an executable files wich if i run into the terminal typing ./FILENAME it starts but when double-clicking on it in files it prompts me with a windows asking to search an application to open the file.

Now in ubuntu executable files are reprrsented by a pink rhombus, and double cliking on them is usually enough, but how can i run within files  in elementary os? Appending a .bin extension may do the trick or what?

Comment: you mean by executable that they are windows or you just misused the word? besides, i do not know exactly the issue as no enough info is provided

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's the [openxcom extended executable](https://openxcom.org/forum/index.php/topic,5258.0.html?PHPSESSID=5hb49op3k2cl96cpc0t7n0gint), in plank i strangely got an icon, see the image:

[image]

I just may make a .desktop file, namely a launcher, or there is a more straightforward way?

Comment: If you right click on the file and choose Properties you can see the `mime-type` and permissions on the file.  The "execute" flag has to be on for at least the user for Files to launch it.  What mime-type is it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a desktop file with the following

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Run Executable
NoDisplay=true
Icon=application-x-executable
Exec=/bin/sh -c 'zenity --question --title="$0" --text="What do you wish to do with this executable file?" --no-wrap --ok-label Execute --cancel-label Cancel && "$0"' %f
Terminal=false
MimeType=application/x-sharedlib
```

name it `run-executable.desktop` and place it in ~/.local/share/applications. You'd be able to execute any executable files by clicking on them. Only problem is, after placing it there, you won't be able to open any executable files in Code to read them. You'd have to install a distro-agnostic text editor like Geany to open them.

I found the answer somewhere, but can't remember who gave it.